# Overloaded method of an interface cannot accept a union type: "No overload matches this call"

Tags: typescript, overloading, union-types

I use a 3rd party library that defines an interface (`A`) with an overloaded method (`method`). The method can accept either null or string value as a parameter.

I define a union type: `string | null` and pass it as a parameter into the method, but I get an error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(val: null): null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'StringOrNull' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(val: string): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'StringOrNull' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2769)
```

Here is my code:
[TypeScript Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG9kChnILYRgAWA9gCYAUAbnADYBcyIArrbQJSMtsDcO+hUpRoNkAZzBRQAc07jJMvgF8sYAJ4AHFAGUFIaQHkoAOVa1kAXnlT9yAD5MzfLDGYgEYYCRD41AMTcEChIAIwArRlQAGmQRRl0bQxMzdmR0flCwgDoCYnJqOnYeZAB6EuQAUSgoEihGYxJkEipoWhI4Mnw4MAQiCDFkYmABhDpaLKwlIA)

```ts
interface A{ 
  method(val: null): null;
  method(val: string): string;
}
type StringOrNull = string | null;

function myFunc(obj: A, val: StringOrNull) {
  obj.method(val); // Error: No overload matches this call.
}
```

Why does this happen and how I can fix this?

Comment: I have three errors in your example. Could you please fix it?

Comment: @captain-yossarian thank you for your comment. I edited my example to include only relevant errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's because none of the overload signatures you provided accept `string | null` as the `val` parameter type. Consider this from the compiler's standpoint, in your `A` interface, you guaranteed that:

1. `method` can accept `null` and return `null`
2. `method` can accept `string` and return `string`

You then passed in a union of `string | null` - the compiler, as expected, complained that there is no `(val: string | null) => unknown` (or similar) signature ("no overload matches this call").

The error message tells you exactly what the compiler tried to do:

1. assign `string | null` to `string` when checking `(val: string) => string` signature
2. assign `string | null` to `null` when checking `(val: null) => null` signature

As you can clearly see, both types of `val` are incompatible with the `StringOrNull` union. I think in this case (and in general, frankly) it is better to write a constrained generic than function overloads (besides, your method is an [identity function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics)):

```ts
interface A{ 
  method<T extends StringOrNull>(val: T) : T;
}

type StringOrNull = string | null;

function myFunc(obj: A, val: StringOrNull) {
  obj.method(val); //OK
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG9kChnILYRgAWA9gCYAUAbnADYBcyAzmFKAOYCUyjLbI7ANxYAvliyhIsRClTJ0OfIVJkAPABVkEAB6QQZJsgDKrDgHkoAOQCutWgD5qdRuu4vhYrGACeABxQm-OwWNnbIALzMpgLIAD7IILa0wlgw1iAIYMAkIPjeAGLpCBQkAEYAVoyoADTINAzG0cFWSdwKuGXlAHQExOROtJyCyAD0I2YA0qJAA)

---

An aside: the handbook 2.0 specifically addresses this pitfall in an [article about overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#writing-good-overloads):

> TypeScript can only resolve a function call to a single overload

A second note stemming from the discussion in comments: if you do not control the declaration of the `A` interface, you can utilize the [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) technique to provide your own signature:

```ts
interface A{ 
  method(val: string) : string;
}

interface A {
  method<T extends StringOrNull>(val: T) : T;
}

type StringOrNull = string | null;

function myFunc(obj: A, val: StringOrNull) {
  obj.method(val); //OK
}
```

In case the interface is imported from a module, you will have to use the above paired with [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have my upvote. Unfortunately, I'm not in control of `interface A`. It comes from a library that I use (I pointed it out in my question). Do you have any recommendations on how I can change the `myFunc` annotation?

Comment: @SergeyGoliney - well (btw, you should probably mention that you can't change the interface itself) - you can utilize interface merging and declare the `A` once again with the generic version of the method - they should get merged, and you will get what you need - I will add a link to the playground shortly

Comment: Another way I see is to extend the interface if you are not a fan of merging, but I think there is not much else you can do if you do not control how the interface is defined

Comment: And if the library is a module the abovementioned can be supplemented with [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to make things work (unless `A` is the default export - in which case you are screwed and will have to patch the interface whenever you use it)

Comment: @SergeyGoliney - NP. Probably would be a good idea to raise that with the 3P lib authors as well - this is a poor way of writing overloads, so they should definitely make an update to typings.

Comment: I don't think I follow: the return type of the two overloads has nothing to do with the issue, which persists even if they are adapted to return the same type.
And the following code (making multiple conditional invocation after having narrowed the union type) also fixes the problem, which is totally nuts to me:https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG9kChnILYRgAWA9gCYAUAbnADYBcyIArrbQJSMtsDcO+hUpRoNkAZzBRQAc05NWtPgF8sWGMxAIwwEiHwBPAGIaEFEgCMAVo1QAaZCMYSpIacgA+8tu2Tp+wGGRqOmQAXnCvDl9+XAtLADoCYnJgjj5cXChCZigQdOQVfjjEwRSRdmUgA

Comment: @FrancescoSalvi the return type doesn't have anything to do with the issue at hand indeed. The OP's problem stems from the fact that they call the method with overloads which lacks a more permissive `string | null` type of the argument with an unnarrowed union type. In your example the calls are made on narrowed types, so the two overloads are enough for the compiler to give its "ok". I recently left the network over the conduct of the company but since this is a comment on my answer, couldn't resist responding .